# Querying two tables according to one search

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with querying mysql tables in a php script.

I have this html script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Human gene catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Reference sequence and Gene Ontology catalog</h1>
<p>
<form action=prueba.php method=post>
<b>1.Select an organism:</b>
<br/>
<input type=radio name=organism value=1>Human
<input type=radio name=organism value=2>Mouse
<input type=radio name=organism value=3>Zebrafish
<input type=radio name=organism value=4>Fruit fly<br/>             
<b>1.Search for a gene:</b>
<br/>
<label>Please select a gene:</label>
<br/>
<input type=text name=gene>
<br/><br/>
<input type=submit name=submit value=Submit>
</form>
</p>
</html>
```

Which generates a section where you have to select the specie and another section where you have to put the query gene.

And I have this php script:

```
<?php
$gene = $_POST["gene"];

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","refGene");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_select_db($enlace,"refGene_human");
$result = mysqli_query($enlace,"select name,name2,chrom,exonCount from refGene_human where name2 like '%$gene%' order by name2");

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Transcript</th><th>Gene</th><th>Chromosome</th <th>ExonCount</th>";

while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$extraido['name']."<br/>";
    echo "<td>".$extraido['name2']."<br/>";
    echo "<td>".$extraido['chrom']."<br/>";
    echo "<td>".$extraido['exonCount']."<br/>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($enlace);
?>
```

What this php code does, is querying the refGene table with the gene name introduced in the html document, and return the corresponding row in the mysql table.

But, now I want to add two things:

1. as you can see in the html document, I want to select either a human table, or others corresponding to other species. This first step is that, if chosen human, connect to the tables with human data, or the ones corresponding to any other specie if another specie other than human is selected.
2. I would like to do another query (I assume something like using the JOIN function in the query), on another table, which has other type of data, and in one field called db_object_symbol, there's the gene name, present in the first table as name2 and being the same that you put in the first html document. Then, return all the fields corresponding to the specific row.

So, to sum up, first selecting one specie in the html, and thus, selecting the two tables corresponding to that specie (I have those two tables for each one), and then according to the gene you write in the html, make the php script return the data in both tables, corresponding to the row or rows where the gene name is present in both tables.

The two tables have this structure:

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| name         | name2     | chrom | strand |
+--------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| NR_046018    | DDX11L1   | chr1  | +      |
| NR_024540    | WASH7P    | chr1  | -      |
| NR_104148    | ZNF107    | chr7  | +      |
| NR_111960    | KDM6A     | chrX  | +      |
| NR_026818    | FAM138A   | chr1  | -      |
| NR_026820    | FAM138F   | chr1  | -      |
| NR_026822    | FAM138C   | chr1  | -      |
| NM_001005484 | OR4F5     | chr1  | +      |
| NR_039983    | LOC729737 | chr1  | -      |
| NR_103753    | LINC00491 | chr5  | -      |
+--------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

And the other table being like:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| db        | db_object_symbol | go_id      |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
| UniProtKB | DNAJC25-GNG10    | GO:0004871 |
| UniProtKB | DNAJC25-GNG10    | GO:0005834 |
| UniProtKB | DNAJC25-GNG10    | GO:0007186 |
| UniProtKB | LOC100509620     | GO:0005215 |
| UniProtKB | LOC100509620     | GO:0006810 |
| UniProtKB | LOC100509620     | GO:0016021 |
| UniProtKB | PPIAL4E          | GO:0000413 |
| UniProtKB | PPIAL4E          | GO:0003755 |
| UniProtKB | PPIAL4E          | GO:0005737 |
| UniProtKB | PPIAL4E          | GO:0006457 |
+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

Where the two fields that have to have the same value is name2 in the first one and db_object_symbol in the second one.

I've been trying some query syntax but it always returns me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need an `UNION`. It's useful when querying, among other things, different tables *with the same columns and data types*, which seems to be your case here.

Something like

```
SELECT name2
FROM table1
WHERE conditions

UNION

SELECT db_object_symbol
FROM table2
WHERE other_conditions
```

should do the trick - I don't know the exact table names so I named them  `table1` and `table2`, obviously. If `name2` and `db_object_symbol` are not of similar types, you may need to perform manual typecasting but otherwise this should work.